# Need Help to make some customization code for stop popup from showing in the mobile mode?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

Please, need some help to stop the popup from showing in mobile devices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
        if(window.location!=window.parent.location){
            jQuery('#newsletter_popup').remove();
        }else{
            if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    beginNewsletterForm();
                }, <?php echo $delay; ?>);
            }
            $('#newsletter_popup_dont_show_again').on('change', function(){
                if($(this).length){        
                    var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
                    if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                        $.cookie('newsletter_popup','dontshowitagain');            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
                        beginNewsletterForm();
                    }
                } else {
                    $.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
                }
            });
        }
    });

function beginNewsletterForm() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'padding': '0px',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#newsletter_popup',
        'onComplete': function() {
            $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
        },
        'tpl': { 
            closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancybox-newsletter-close" href="javascript:;"></a>' 
        }
    });
    jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<?php
    if($popup["newsletter_custom_style"]){
        echo $popup["newsletter_custom_style"];
    }
?>
#newsletter_popup{
<?php
    if($popup["newsletter_width"]){
        echo "width:".$popup["newsletter_width"].";";
    }
    if($popup["newsletter_height"]){
        echo "height:".$popup["newsletter_height"].";";
    }
    if($popup["newsletter_bg_color"]){
        echo "background-color:".$popup["newsletter_bg_color"].";";
    }
    if(isset($popup["newsletter_bg_image"]) && $popup["newsletter_bg_image"]){
?>
    background-image:url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."porto/newsletter_popup/".$popup['newsletter_bg_image'];?>);
<?php
    }
?>
}
</style>
<div class="block block-subscribe" id="newsletter_popup">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-popup-validate-detail" onsubmit="setNewsletterCookie()">
        <div class="block-content">
            <?php
                if($popup["show_logo"]){
            ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($popup["show_logo"]); ?>" alt="" />
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            <?php echo $popup['newsletter_content']; ?>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter_popup_email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__("Email Address"); ?>" />
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Go!') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Go!') ?></span></span></button>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterpopupSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-popup-validate-detail');
        document.getElementById("newsletter-popup-validate-detail").onsubmit=function(){
            jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup','dontshowitagain');
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
    <div class="subscribe-bottom">
        <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again"/>
        <label for="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again"><?php echo $this->__("Don't show this popup again"); ?></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide your popup by adding a style by giving display none using media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.block-subscribe {display: none !important;}
}
```

or You have the popup id

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#newsletter_popup {display: none !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hidden class on your popup.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.hidden {display:none !important}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work